# Sending password reset email with django

Tags: django

I have a small blog that developing. I want to send an email containing a link to a password reset page after a user signs up using only email.

```
def email_signUp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'email_subscription' in request.POST:
            form = EmailForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['email'].split('@')[0]
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password1 = passgen()

                User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password1)
```

How can I send the email? I already have password reset page accessible at `'password_reset/'`

Am using

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is Quick example ->

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.', #after you will create user object you can send in message api url like localhost:8000/password_reset/
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```